# refresh div with new data as if it was a page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is it possible using jQuery to literally refresh a `div`?

Nothing like submitting a form or anything like that.

I have a data stream which is updated else where and all I want to do is refresh the div and all its contents as if it were a page refresh. I can't link to that page to make a return that populates as the only output is just raw data.

The div itself contains all the data display processing. Nothing needs to be fetched as the data is already there.

Comment: Yes it is possible. If you show us your code and an excerpt of your raw data, we could help you figure it out.

Comment: You mean if the service isn't intelligently backed? You could use a `load()` with a selector, but it's gonna pull in a lot of needless HTML.

Comment: the data come in an array. which I break apart in a foreach.
`<div class="resorts">
    <?php foreach ( $results['resorts'] as $resort ) { ?>
    <table class="resortsTable" id="tblbtborder">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="12" class="resortImagesTable">
        <?php $resortID = $resort->resortID ?>`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use setinterval with ajax function,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ refreshDiv(); }, someInterval); 
}); 

function refreshDiv(){
$.ajax({
  url: "http://yourrequestpath",
  .....
 });
}
```

Comment: I have tried using an Ajax function but the Ajax function only loads the data and page structure from the file it links to instead of using the html and php structure already on the page

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="data"></div>

<script>
$('#div').load("loaddata.php", function() {
    window.setInterval("loadData", 60000);
});

function loadData()
{
    $('#div').load("loaddata.php");
}
</script>
```